# conditions in permutation and combination when two object can be assumed as single element

Tags: permutations, combinations

There are some scenrio when we can consider two distinct element as a single element and calculate permutation eg.

> In how many ways can 5 objects be arranged in a row so that two object
>   x and y are together ?

Here I can assume two objects x and y as a single element and calculate the permutation which gives

> 4!2!

Now following question:

> How many 7 digit numbers are there such that the digits are distinct
>   integers taken from $$\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$$
>
> and such that the digits 5 and 6 do not appear consecutively in either
>   other ?

In this question if I solve this by considering 5 and 6 as single unit then the result is $$P(9,7)-2*P(8,6)$$ which is wrong answer.

> Right answer is $$P(9,7)-2*6*P(7,5)$$

Please guide the scenrio where to assume objects as single unit and where not ?

Comment: Your error is in calculating the $2\cdot P(8,6)$ term.  You need to subtract *very specifically* the situations where a $5$ and a $6$ *actually occur* next to eachother.  How many of those are there?  First, we can temporarily let $5$ and $6$ be glued together, call it $X$.  Now... how many length $6$ strings taken from $\{1,2,3,4,7,8,9,X\}$ with all distinct characters **contain $X$** (*this is what you forgot about*).

Comment: To count this, first pick where the $X$ occurs in the length $6$ string (*6 possibilities*).  Then for the remaining five spaces, one at a time fill in with other characters from $\{1,2,3,4,7,8,9\}$ (*P(7,5) possibilities*).  Finally, remember that we were using an $X$ instead of a $5$ and a $6$, so "unglue" the $X$ back to how it was and decide whether the $5$ was before the $6$ or vice versa (*2 possibilities*).

Comment: @JMoravitz : I have the answer of the question and reason about it . I want to know what is going wrong in $$$P(9,7)−2∗P(8,6)$

Comment: I thought I was clear about that already, but in $P(8,6)$ that implies that you are making a string of length $6$ from $\{1,2,3,4,7,8,9,X\}$, and that string might not even have $X$ in it.  You could have been subtracting the string `312478` for example, which wasn't one we wanted to "remove" since it wasn't a "bad length 7 string."  The $2$ in $2\cdot P(8,6)$ is for whether $X$ should be replaced by $5,6$ or by $6,5$... which doesn't matter if $X$ wasn't even in the string that you picked.

Comment: Ohh , you mean we may or may not choose X in the string but I removed other permutations as well thats why I got the wrong answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should split up in $4$ cases:

- the selected $7$ distinct digits contain $5$ and do not contain $6$.
- the selected $7$ distinct digits contain $6$ and do not contain $5$.
- the selected $7$ distinct digits do not contain $6$ and do not contain $5$.
- the selected $7$ distinct digits contain $6$ and contain $5$.

In the first 3 cases the condition that $5$ and $6$ do not appear consecutively is irrelevant.

Solution: $\binom767!+\binom767!+\binom777!+\binom75(7!-6!2!)$

Comment: @Mukeshkumarsaini for the first case, "the selected seven digits contain a 5 and do not contain a six."  First step, pick which digits *appear* (*we'll take care of in what order later*).  We know that a 5 must appear, so we have to still pick what the other six digits are out of the 7 remaining: $\binom{7}{6}$ ways to do this.  Now that we know what the seven digits are (our 5 plus the other six digits picked in the previous step) we arrange them in a line in $7!$ ways, giving $\binom{7}{6}7!$ possibilities.  Alternatively, pick position of the $5$ then fill in the rest for $7P(7,6)$ ways.

Comment: That being said, @drhab did make a mistake, not recognizing that zeroes are not in our list of available digits, or in some other way mistakenly used $\binom{8}{6}$ instead of $\binom{7}{6}$ for the first two terms.

Comment: @JMoravitz : I think drhab considered the zero otherwise it should be $C(9,6)$

Comment: @drhab I didnot get 4th case clearly . Although it may be too simple

Comment: Out of time now. Later I will come back to have a closer look (and eventually delete). Sorry for mistakes (if they are there).

Comment: @Mukeshkumarsaini $\{1,2,3,4,\color{red}{5},\color{blue}{6},7,8,9\}$  There are seven (not nine) black numbers there.  In the first case, we wish to pick six black numbers to be paired with our red number.  Pick which six of the *seven available* black numbers (*not 9 numbers, we don't want to accidentally pick a $5$ or a $6$ in this step*).

Comment: In the fourth case, to explain that, pick which five of the black numbers will appear with our red and blue number, so $\binom{7}{5}$ ways to pick the five black numbers.  Next, we glue the $5$ and the $6$ together to make an $\color{purple}{X}$.  We take our five black numbers and our $\color{purple}{X}$ and arrange them in a line in $6!$ ways.  Finally, we unglue the $\color{purple}{X}$ as either a $\color{red}{5}\color{blue}{6}$ or a $\color{blue}{6}\color{red}{5}$ (2 ways).  Applying multiplication principle then $\binom{7}{5}6!\cdot 2$

Comment: @JMoravitz : What I mean should we include 4th case because I do not want them to appear together and yes I got your previous point

Comment: As @JMoravitz noticed I made mistakes. Actually two sort of mistakes. One involving the first two cases and one involving the fourth case (sorry). I have done some repairing now and hope that things are okay and clear now.